# Cordova geolocation fails when turned on after the app was started

Tags: html, cordova, geolocation

i'm having this thing on a cordova app (on Android; on iOS works just fine) that implies some location issues. Let me explain:

Since the app requires a location check at start-up, I display a warning message with a retry button.

So i have this very simple scenario:

1. start the app with the location turned off. The warning is shown
2. Turn the location on, then retry to locate
3. the location is still not detected

I have this very simple testcase:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(e){ console.log(e) },
  function(e){ console.log(e) },
  {
    enableHighAccuracy : true
  }
);
```

Any idea of what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and no idea why it happens, but I solved it this way:

- use `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` instead of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` ;
- be it on success or on error, call `clearWatch`.

A subsequent call to `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` should be successful even if the GPS/location was not turned on at the first time.

This solution does however not work on iOS, so that you should insert a platform detection.

Does it make sense ?